# Помогите с пагинацией MySQL, нужно решить задачу

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть блок с поиском по логину заблокированного юзера и логину администратору, при изменении любого поля (логина юзера или логина админа) посылается запрос к файлу, сложность в том, что у таблицы структура

1. UUID пользователя
2. Логин администратора блокировщика

Но связка (логин юзера-UUID) хранится в другой таблице и Ник хранится 1 раз, а поиск нужно сделать через LIKE по логину, при этом записей с логином пользователя и логином админа может быть несколько одинаковых.

Нужно сделать выборку, имея логин админа, логин пользователя (оба неполные) и вернуть все записи, даже если среди них будет 2 записи где Один и тот же логин админа и логин пользователя.

При всём этом в запросе должен быть LIMIT 0,10 что бы я мог поставить свои значения и сделать пагинацию. Пытался сделать несколькими запросами и через циклы пытаться получить такой эффект, вышел «скрипт через жопу»

Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Связывать записи через логин пользователя плохая идея. Напишите ваш текущий код с запросом

Comment: @ArchDemon структуру базы делал не я и изменять её не могу.

Answer (score -2):

Пагинация (вывод номеров страниц в виде ссылок) делается методом следующим, узнаётся id записи начальной, id записи конечной, делается цикл, в нём идёт проверка на отсутствие остатка от деления на 10 (где 10, это сколько нужно показывать записей на странице одной), в ссылках делается параметр HTTP GET ?page_id=$i. Цикл продолжается до записи конечной $idCurr < $idMax

Comment: Слушай, а ты в принципе текст вопроса-то читаешь? Или видишь одно ключевое слово в заголовке и кидаешься строчить ответ?